# Unexpected output from read.table clipboard option?

Tags: r, csv, clipboard, read.table

I have a `csv` file with 10198 rows and 16 columns. When I use the following code, it seems like I am missing some data:

```
dat = read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
> dim(dat)
[1] 9633   16
```

while `read.csv` returns correct data:

```
dat = read.csv(file = "PRM.csv", sep = "", header = TRUE)
> dim(dat)
[1] 10198    16
```

Does anybody know what is going on here? Is a reproducable dataset required for this?

Comment: the `sep` argument dictates how the file is read and what R uses as the gap (or delimiter) between columns. You are missing some in the first one because columns are not always separated by a tab (`\t`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is that in first line you use a wrong sep field, try to use:

```
dat = read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

and also try to add an extension to your file, e.g. clipboard.txt